# Number of maximum disk on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am looking for a answer for a question over Amazon EC2.

As we can add multiple EBS which can be of 1TB in size, so how many of them i can add on a single EC2 instance?

Couldn't find the answer on goolge if there is someone who've experienced it or can refer something, that will be great help thanks.

Comment: I'm curious what you searched for that didn't turn up this URL as the first hit: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_limits.html

Comment: Also 1TB is the max size of a Magnetic EBS volume. Other EBS volume types like general purpose SSD have a max size of 16TB.

Comment: @MarkB i got the answer on the serverfualt, at http://serverfault.com/questions/359705/how-many-ebs-drives-i-can-mount-on-a-single-ec2-instance-using-amazon-web-servic but i forgot to delete the question. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The maximum number of volumes that your instance can have depends on the operating system. When considering how many volumes to add to your instance, you should consider whether you need increased I/O bandwidth or increased storage capacity.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_limits.html

For Linux, there is apparently a soft (recommended) limit of 40, while for Windows there is a hard limit, which can be 26 or 17 depending on the virtualization implementation in use.

Note also that [most EBS volumes can be up to 16 TB in size](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html) rather than 1 TB, which is a limit that only applies to the [legacy magnetic volume type](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/previous-generation/).

Comment: Thank you so much it has the necessary links along with that and that too from Amazon.